# having cell show a paticular number if the answer in the formula in the cell is a certain number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

so I don't know if it's possible but I want to have a cell show a particular percentage in the formula I put in the cell comes up with a particular answer. for example, if I put in the formula =6/3 and the answer is 2 I want it to instead of showing a 2 to show a 75%.

Comment: can you explain the 75%?

Answer (score 0):

This question is VERY VERY vague.

At the very least you will need IF combined with conditional formatting and even then it is dependent on where that data came from. You can't just replace the answer of a cell with a different result since that new result itself will be computed.

Comment: Ok in the end I need the cell to display 75% when a formula equals a 2. How would u set it up. IDC if I have set up a space on the sheet to do the math I just need a particular percentage to appear in a specific cell when the formula I designate has a specific amount. So 2 would need a 75% a 3 would need a 80%.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying (in your comment on the first answer) that you are computing a value (e.g., `=6/3`, which evaluates to 2) in one cell -- let’s call it `X1` -- and you want your mysteriously related number to appear somewhere else -- let’s say that’s cell `A1`. 
First of all, you should put clarifying information like that back into the question (by [editing](https://superuser.com/posts/669057/edit) it), and not (just) in comments.

Secondly, a simple solution of mapping one number to another would be to put the following into `A1`:

> `=IF(X1=2, "75%", IF(X1=3, "80%", IF (X1=4,`*`value_for_4`*`,`*`default_value`*`)))`

Or consider

```
=(X1+13)/20
```

If that is, in fact, the general formula.